# os.system() failing in python

Tags: python, gnuplot, os.system

I'm trying to parse some data and make graphs with python and there's an odd issue coming up. A call to `os.system()` seems to get lost somewhere.

The following three lines:

```
os.system('echo foo bar')
os.system('gnuplot test.gnuplot')
os.system('gnuplot --version')
```

Should print:

```
foo bar
Warning: empty x range [2012:2012], adjusting to [1991.88:2032.12]
gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 2
```

But the only significant command in the middle seems to get dropped. The script still runs the echo and version check, and running `gnuplot` by itself (the gnuplot shell) works too, but there is no warning and no file output from gnuplot.

**Why is this command dropped, and why completely silently?**

In case it's helpful, the invocation should start gnuplot, it should open a couple of files (the instructions and a data file indicated therein) and write out to an SVG file. I tried deleting the target file so it wouldn't have to overwrite, but to no avail.

This is python 3.2 on Ubuntu Natty x86_64 virtual machine with the 2.6.38-8-virtual kernel.

Comment: Check the return code from os.system. Is it 0 (success)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turned out the issue was something I failed to mention. Earlier in the script test.gnuplot and test.data were written, but I neglected to call the file objects' `close()` and verify that they got closed (still don't know how to do that last part so for now it cycles for a bit). So there was some unexpected behaviour going on there causing gnuplot to see two unreadable files, take no action, produce no output, and return 0.

I guess nobody gets points for this one.

Edit: I finally figured it out with the help of `strace`. Don't know how I did things before I [learned how to use it](http://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/strace_the_sysadmin_s_microscope).

Answer (score 2):

Is the warning printed to stderr, and that is intercepted somehow?

Try using subprocess instead, for example using

```
subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

and checking the output.

(or plaing subprocess.call might work better than os.system)

Comment: For reference, the subprocess docs: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess

Answer (score 1):

don't use `os.system`. Use [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess).

[`os.system` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.system) says:

> *The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function.*

Try this:

```
subprocess.check_call(['gnuplot', 'test.gnuplot'])
```